# Error al actualizar Div automaticamente

Tags: div

Tengo un chat y necesito que se actualice automaticamente mandando el scroll automatico hasta abajo, el problema es que al momento de recargar el div se me incrusta TODA la página web en ese div, les dejo el código y el error:

[image: Muestra del error que me arroja en consola]

```
<div id="chat"></div>//DIV QUE DESEO RECARGAR
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
    $('#chat').load(perfil2-chat.php);//actualizo el div
   }, 1000 );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Desarrolla más la pregunta, añade los demás archivos que intervienen, perfil2-chat.php, ¿qué contiene?, no podremos ayudarte a arreglar lo que falle si no podemos ver qué falla

Comment: Tengo aprox 1600 lineas de código y stack no me deja colocar todas, dentro de perfil2-chat.php tengo menu, contenido dinamico php etc, coloque la referencia del div del chat ya que es el que me anda generando problemas.

Comment: Puedes adjuntar a tu pregunta el error que te aparece en consola o tu IDE al hacer debug..

Comment: Listo, actualice la pregunta con el pantallaso del error en consola

Comment: Tal como te señala el error es la versión de JQuery que haces referencia no es la que pide Boostrap esto puede deberse a que hay muchas referencia de JQuery que se entrecruzan, el orden de como llamas a la referencia JQuery o por ultimo la versión  que estas usando.

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en como llamas a tu pagina php en el [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) debería ser entre comillas dobles o simple de la siguiente forma.

```
$('#chat').load('perfil2-chat.php');//actualizo el div
   }, 1000 );
```

Comment: Si, fue error mio colocar la muestra así, pero en mi código si lo tengo así y me sigue el error